# What does 3MPL refer to?

Tags: morphology, interlinear-gloss

" b. Ha-yeladim kul-am zarku ʔavanim. 
the children all-3MPL threw stones 
‘The children all threw stones."
In this example, what does '3MPL' mean?

Comment: Knowing Hebrew, yup, 3mp(l) means what it normally means here. Specifically the suffix on "all" matches the antecedent.

Comment: Moreover this is clearly homework

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where this notation comes from and what it means](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/28868/where-this-notation-comes-from-and-what-it-means)

Comment: @LukeSawczak Homework it may be, but nobody is asking us to do it for them, so it's not a "homework question".

Comment: @Wilson Eh, when it looks like it's copied and pasted verbatim, without any evidence of thinking through it and running up against a wall, without any hint of having used widely available resources, I'm inclined to ask for those things first. Answering it is still a nice thing to do, but I don't think it enriches the site much.

Answer (score 5):

This sentence is glossed (sort of—not completely) according to the [Leipzig Glossing Rules](https://www.eva.mpg.de/lingua/resources/glossing-rules.php). The appendix lists the most common abbreviations, and indeed, everything here is in that list:

- `3` = third person
- `M` = masculine
- `PL` = plural

A more standard glossing would be `3.M.PL`, with dots between the abbreviations. And a full gloss would look something like this:

> Ha=yelad-im kul-am zarku ʔavan-im
>   The=child-PL all-3.M.PL threw stone-PL

Hebrew verb morphology is complicated (and breaks a lot of Euro-centric models of morphology) so I would probably just leave *zarku* as-is.